# How to color the font of a single row in a table, while using a paragraph column?

Tags: tables, color, paragraphs

I tried to color the text of the headers of my tables. Sadly it doesn't work properly as soon as you use it with paragraph columns.

Below is my MWE presented. The `header` in the first table is as I want it to be. Unfortunately the table is too long, so I need a paragraph column for the right column. But when I use this, I get problems with the layout (see second table in picture).

Can anyone tell me, why this happens and/or how to correct it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\@rowstyle}{}

\newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{% sets the style of the next row
  \gdef\@rowstyle{#1}%
  \@rowstyle\ignorespaces%
}

\newcolumntype{=}{% resets the row style
  >{\gdef\@rowstyle{}}%
}

\newcolumntype{+}{% adds the current row style to the next column
  >{\@rowstyle}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{=l +l}
  \rowstyle{\color{red}}
Kategorie & Behandelte Frage(n) \\
\bfseries Usability & Ist das System einfach und intuitiv zu bedienen?\\
\bfseries Adaptability & Kann man das System an die eigenen Prozesse anpassen? Gibt es     eigene Workflows und Felder?\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{25pt}

\begin{tabular}{=l +p{9cm}}
  \rowstyle{\color{red}}
Kategorie & Behandelte Frage(n) \\
\bfseries Usability & Ist das System einfach und intuitiv zu bedienen?\\
\bfseries Adaptability & Kann man das System an die eigenen Prozesse anpassen? Gibt es     eigene Workflows und Felder?\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE with 2 Tables]

Answer (score 4):

The text in the `p` and the `X` column (which uses in the default setting a `p` column) will get moved to the second line. The cells themselves are top-aligned.

While I don’t know what `\color` exactly does, the result can be reproduced with

```
\hrulefill                       \par
\parbox[t]{8cm}{\color{red}Text} \par
\hrulefill
```

#### References

- [Function and usage of \leavevmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/function-and-usage-of-leavevmode)
- [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) describes  the different between `\color` and `\textcolor` in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86040/16595) to [What is the difference between \textcolor and \color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86039/16595)
- [Another answer of him](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119798/16595) (but it’s not his fault)
- [\color after inline section colors the section title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3504/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,xcolor,tabularx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{% sets the style of the next row
  \gdef\@rowstyle{\leavevmode#1}%
  \@rowstyle\ignorespaces}
\newcolumntype{=}{>{\gdef\@rowstyle{}}}
\newcolumntype{+}{>{\@rowstyle}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{=l +l}
    \rowstyle{\color{red}} Kategorie & Behandelte Frage(n)                                                                        \\
    \bfseries Usability              & Ist das System einfach und intuitiv zu bedienen?                                           \\
    \bfseries Adaptability           & Kann man das System an die eigenen Prozesse anpassen? Gibt es eigene Workflows und Felder?
\end{tabular}

\vspace{25pt}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{=l +p{8cm}}
    \rowstyle{\color{red}} Kategorie & Behandelte Frage(n)                                                                        \\
    \bfseries Usability              & Ist das System einfach und intuitiv zu bedienen?                                           \\
    \bfseries Adaptability           & Kann man das System an die eigenen Prozesse anpassen? Gibt es eigene Workflows und Felder?
\end{tabular}

\vspace{25pt}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{=l +X}
    \rowstyle{\color{red}} Kategorie & Behandelte Frage(n)                                                                        \\
    \bfseries Usability              & Ist das System einfach und intuitiv zu bedienen?                                           \\
    \bfseries Adaptability           & Kann man das System an die eigenen Prozesse anpassen? Gibt es eigene Workflows und Felder?
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]